# mysql select regexp like with "full-stop"

Tags: mysql, regex

have that little sql select:

```
select * from import_daten WHERE lastname REGEXP 'dipl\.|dr\.';
```

And just want to filter the rows with ing. and dipl. but with that statement i also get the people wtih for e.g. "Abendroth" in Lastname. Because the "dr" in Name.

Same is with

```
select * from import_daten WHERE lastname REGEXP 'dipl.|dr.';
```

How is it possible to include the full-stop correct within the regexp?

Comment: I see no way that "Abendroth" can match that regex.

Comment: ohh...sorry. i'didnt meant ing. i meant dr.. I have changed it in the question. so with 'dipl.|ing.' you're right, that can't match "Abendroth" but the "dr." matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REGEXP '(dipl|dr)[.]'
```

Be careful of start/end of word:

```
mysql> SELECT 'dr.' REGEXP 'dr[.][[:>:]]', 'dr.' REGEXP 'dr[.]';
+-----------------------------+----------------------+
| 'dr.' REGEXP 'dr[.][[:>:]]' | 'dr.' REGEXP 'dr[.]' |
+-----------------------------+----------------------+
|                           0 |                    1 |
+-----------------------------+----------------------+
```

Notice how it fails?  That is because `.` is not a character that can exist in a 'word'.

Also, I used `[.]` instead of `\.` because of the problem of escaping the escape character -- in some situations you need `\\.`; in others you might need `\\\\.`.  Too confusing.

If necessary you can use 'word start':  `REGEXP '[[:<:]](dipl|dr)[.]'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this

```
select * from import_daten WHERE lastname REGEXP '(dipl\.)|(ing\.)';
```

Comment: hmm, thx, but not really. with that i also fetch the "abendroth's" but i just want the "Dr. Abenroth".

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make sure the pattern is at a "word boundary." MySQL's regular expression syntax has special character sequences for that:

```
select * from import_daten WHERE lastname REGEXP '[[:<:]](dipl\.|dr\.)[[:>:]]';
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html. It's nearly the last item on the page before that page's user comments.